# How to test if module exists before you loaded it in R?

Tags: r

I have code like this:

```
  analysisModules <-
    list(
      list(
        module = "divosLongitudinal",
        type = "RAW_DATA_TRELLIS",
        displayName = "Raw Data Trellis"
      ),
      ...
    )
  for(module in analysisModules) {
    tryCatch({
      library(module$module, character.only = TRUE)
      .analysisModules$analysisModule[[module$type]] <- module
    }, error = function() {
      print(paste("missing module", module$module))
    })
  }
```

I've added tryCatch because some modules may be missing, but when I run this code, I've got this error:

```
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6541 Loading environments/devProfile.R
 Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: unused argument (cond) Stack trace
 (innermost first):
     40: tryCatchOne
     39: tryCatchList
     38: tryCatch
     37: server [C:\projects\divosshiny\inst\app/server.R#145]
      1: runApp Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unused argument (cond)
```

line 145 is `tryCatch({`

How can I skip packages that where not installed?

Comment: Use `require()` rather than `library()`. `require()` will return TRUE/FALSE depending on whether the package actually loaded.

Comment: But this particular error message is because the function you passed to the `error=` parameter doesn't accept the error parameter. Same error with this `tryCatch(stop("boo"), error=function() print("booed"))` but this works: `tryCatch(stop("boo"), error=function(e) print("booed"))`

Comment: @MrFlick require don't work with strings. got error: Warning in if `(!loaded) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
c("Loading required package: $", "Loading required package: module", "Loading required package: module")
Failed with error:  ‘'package' must be of length 1’`

Comment: You can `Vectorize()` `require()`: `Vectorize(require)(package.name.vector, character.only=TRUE)`

Comment: adding `e` parameter resolved the issue, thanks.